# wp, shortcode content not visible in homepage, but visible in post

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

So I created this simple shortcode, which accepts a few params and it works as expected in the post page. I add a new post, implement the shortcode code and it all works great. But when I see the post in the homepage, it only shows the title not the content. Is there any wp code shortcode that I should implement in my shortcode in order to be able to see the content that the shortcode outputs, from the homepage/search results too?

```
function curr_func( $atts ) {

    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'am' => '',
        'c1' => '',
        'c2' => '',
    ), $atts );

    $output = "The text I output";

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'fx', 'curr_func' );
```

This is the shortcode and I use it like
fx[ ...parameters ];

I have added this as a plugin. IS there any easy fix for this?

Comment: `fx[parameters]`? I mean, it should be `[fx parameters /]`, as in `[fx am="" c1="" c2="" /]`.

Comment: Yes, like you said. The shortcode works okay this way [fx am="" c1="" c2="" /]


I meant the content is not displayed on home thats the problem

Comment: I see. And one option you can try, is by using [custom excerpt](https://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt), which means you'd use the `[fx]` Shortcode in both the full post content and its excerpt/summary *editors* (i.e. `textarea` boxes). Alternatively, in [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action), use `the_content()` and not `the_excerpt()` or similar functions.